# Tags trend in stack exchange

Tags: discussion, tags

We have some trend analysis in stack overflow. Like this one: http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tagtrend.html.

And I can also see the overall count of questions based on each tag, as shown below:

[image]

However, understanding the trending of questions could also be interesting as we can have a better understanding on what people are learning and what the industry in focusing on. By comparing things like Visualforce and lightning we might have a better understanding of the market share as well.

Has anyone done some work on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some simple search terms based on tag, date, and a few other filters. Some example terms:

```
[visualforce] is:question created:2016-09
[lightning] is:answer created:2015-01
isaccepted:yes created:2016-01
```

Just looking at the two tags you singled out and comparing them to the system totals, here's the data from last September (when the first `[lightning]` questions started appearing) through the end of last month:

```
Tag          Total Questions  Total Answers  Total Accepted  Answers/Question  Accept %
all          19936            21528          7968            1.08              39.97%
visualforce  3950             4331           1677            1.10              42.46%
lightning    498              435            174             0.87              34.94%
```

So `[visualforce]` questions are answered at a slightly higher frequency than questions in general, and are also slighlty more likely to have an accepted answer. In contrast, `[lightning]` questions see notably fewer answers, and are also less likely to have an accepted answer.

Here are some charts from the beginning of last year:

[image: Questions]

[image: Answers]

[image: Answers/Question]

[image: Accept %]

As you can see, `[lightning]` is gaining some ground, but `[visualforce]` is actually holding fairly steady with a pretty flat trend line this year, and still more popular than at the start of 2015.

Comment: Hi Adrian, how did you generate this graph? Did you use [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/queries)? I'm keen to how the `[marketing-cloud]` tag is trending.

Comment: Just dumped search results into a Google Sheet. @Eliot